# Cardinal Arithmetic - Right or Wrong?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

> ${\,}| {\Bbb{R}} {\rightarrow} {\Bbb{N}} {\,}| = {\,}| {\Bbb{N}}^{\Bbb{R}} {\,}| = \aleph_0^{\aleph} = \aleph_0{^2}^{\aleph_0}$
>
> ${\,} | {\Bbb{R}} {\times} ({\Bbb{R}} \rightarrow \{0,1\}) {\,}| = |{\Bbb{R}}| \cdot|{\Bbb{R}}\rightarrow\{0,1\}| = \aleph \cdot 2^{\aleph} = 2^{\aleph_0} \cdot 2^{\aleph} = 2^{\aleph_0 + \aleph} = 2^{\aleph}$
>
> $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \aleph \, \,$ ?

Any more ways to simplify the expressions ? are they right ?

Any references for more complex cardinal arithmetic ?

**Thank you.**

Comment: Yup they are correct!

Comment: Can i say that $\aleph_0{^2}^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{2\cdot\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \aleph$ ?

Comment: Note: A more common notation (AFAIK) for $2^{\aleph_0}$ is $\mathfrak c$ - the cardinality of continuum.

Comment: @YarivLevy  you can say that only if you left out some parentheses.  $\aleph_0{^2}^{\aleph_0}$ would normally be read as $\aleph_0^{(2^{\aleph_0})} $  If you meant $(\aleph_0^2)^{\aleph_0} $ you can.  This is just like finite exponents

Comment: Can you say that $2^{2^3}=2^6$?